# Route access check for local task

Tags: 8

I've created a view with a page display, filtering on a specific node type. The view's URL is `/admin/poi`.

Now I want to create a local task, linking to this view, for all nodes of type `poi`. The local task is showing, but it is visible when viewing/editing any node type, not just my POIs.

wt_poi.routing.yml

```
wt_poi.admin_list:
  path: '/admin/poi'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'access administration pages'
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\wt_poi\Controller\WtPoiController::isAllowedPoiAdminList'
  options:
    _admin_route: true
```

wt_poi.links.task.yml

```
wt_poi.list_overview:
  route_name: wt_poi.admin_list
  base_route: entity.node.canonical
  title: 'List all POIs'
  weight: -9999
```

src/Controller/WtPoiController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\wt_poi\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

/**
 * Controller for the POI node type tasks.
 *
 */
class WtPoiController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * Used to limit visibility of local task "List" to POI node type
   */
  public function isAllowedPoiAdminList() {
    $bundle = false;
    $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
      $bundle = $node->bundle();
    }
    return AccessResult::forbiddenIf($bundle !== 'poi');
  }
}
```

Why is my `_custom_access` check not hiding the local task on other node types?

UPDATE: There seems to be an access check, but it is coming from "Access" in views module "Page settings" and my own access check is completly ignored. Best case would be my access check in addition to the view's access check, in a pinch I would prefer my own custom check replacing the view's access check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround. When I add the view's URL as path in `routing.yml`, Drupal always used the view's access check. So instead of directly using the view's path, I wrote a simple redirect controller in order to get an alternative path.

wt_poi.routing.yml

```
wt_poi.admin_list:
  path: '/admin/poi-redirect'
  defaults:
    _controller: '\Drupal\wt_poi\Controller\WtPoiController::redirectToPoiAdminList'
  requirements:
    _permission: 'administer nodes'
    _custom_access: '\Drupal\wt_poi\Controller\WtPoiController::isAllowedPoiAdminList'
  options:
    _admin_route: true
```

wt_poi.links.task.yml remains unchanged

src/Controller/WtPoiController.php

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\wt_poi\Controller;

use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;
use Drupal\Core\Access\AccessResult;

/**
 * Controller for the POI node type tasks.
 *
 */
class WtPoiController extends ControllerBase {

  /**
   * The only purpose of this controller is to provide an
   * alternative path to the POI view, so we can attach an
   * _custom_access check to it.
   */
  public function redirectToPoiAdminList() {
    // redirecting to a view: view.VIEW_MACHINE_NAME.DISPLAY_MACHINE_NAME
    return $this->redirect('view.poi.admin_list');
  }

  /**
   * Used to limit visibility of local Task "List" to POI node types
   */
  public function isAllowedPoiAdminList() {
    $bundle = false;
    $route = \Drupal::routeMatch();
    $routeName = $route->getRouteName();
    $node = $route->getParameter('node');
    if ($node instanceof \Drupal\node\NodeInterface) {
      $bundle = $node->bundle();
    }
    // the first part ensures the local task is shown on node pages,
    // the second part makes sure it also works during the redirection itself
    return AccessResult::allowedIf($bundle === 'poi' || $routeName === 'wt_poi.admin_list');
  }
}
```

Two remarks:

A) Remember that the user still has to pass the view's own permission check after the redirection (and this is a good thing, otherwise anybody knowing the alternative URL could bypass the access check).

B) The access check must use an `allowedIf($positiveCondition)`. Do not use an `forbiddenIf($negativeCondition)`, because it only returns `forbidden` or `neutral`, which always hides the local task.

My solution still feels a bit hacky, and I still would be open for a cleaner solution, but at least it does everything I need.

Comment: Instead of a redirect you could override the Views permission/route?

Comment: I guess this would not work: Initially my access check was a simple `AccessResult::allowedIf($bundle === 'poi')`. This did work as a filter for the local task, but the redirecting itself stopped working (the link was there, but after clicking I got a "permission denied" because I no longer was in a POI-node route). So I always allowed the redirection route itself. I fear I would run into the same problem if I add this check to the view, but I can't use the "always allow self route" trick for this restricted administrative view.

Answer (score 0):

For others who find this page, it took me hours to figure out how to do something similar: have a Views tab on certain node types.

This post helped, but in the end I found what I really needed to do was create a Views Access Plugin.

I created a step-by-step blog post with pictures all about it, here:
https://peacocksoftware.com/blog/drupal-89-views-tab-only-certain-node-types